# How to use the second conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

"It **doesn't** matter to me if you were a thief, I'd still love you the same way."

Does this question follow the rules of how the 2nd conditional should be used?
If we changed the highlighted **doesn't** to **wouldn't**, would the meaning of the sentence still be the same? How do you interpret the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the original sentence as not-quite-grammatical.

"It doesn't matter to me if you were a thief..."

I don't know what it means.  **doesn't** and **if you were** don't jibe.  I want to change it to either

It doesn't matter to me *that* you were a thief...

or

It *wouldn't* matter to me if you were a thief...

Comment: _"It doesn't matter to me if you **are** a thief," / _"It **didn't** matter to me **that** you **were** a thief."_